# Do all the following word orders sound natural? Is there a difference in meaning?

Tags: gramática, orden-de-palabras

Do all of the following sound natural? Is there a difference in meaning?

1. El hombre leía el libro a la niña.
2. Leía el hombre el libro a la niña.
3. A la niña le leía el hombre el libro.
4. El libro lo leía el hombre a la niña.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a matter of emphasis. Without context, the most natural option is

- El hombre leía el libro a la niña

But you might want to emphasize "la niña", in which case you can mention her first. For example:

- El niño leía el libro solo porque ya había aprendido a leer. *A la niña le leía el hombre el libro*.

Or you might want to emphasize "el libro" and mention it first:

- Había una revista y un libro para entretenerse. La revista la leía normalmente el niño. *El libro **se** lo leía el hombre a la niña*.

The additional **se** is a case of a duplicate indirect object pronoun, similar to **le** in sentence 3.

The other example (sentence 2.) is less common in spoken language, and sounds more poetic/literary to me. But it is also correct: you might well find it in a novel or a poem.